# Error while installing opencv File "/home/oem/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skbuild/__init__.py", line 19

Tags: python, opencv, pip

```
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-twfSTx/opencv-python/setup.py", line 9, in <module>
    import skbuild
  File "/home/oem/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skbuild/__init__.py", line 19
    def __dir__() -> List[str]:
                  ^
**SyntaxError: invalid syntax**

----------------------------------------
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: The question is unclear. You just posted an error message. Please tell us what command did you run to install opencv? Also is this the complete Traceback?

Comment: That's type annotation syntax only introduced in Python 3, but you're trying to use the code on the long-obsolete Python 2. So either update your Python to something more current, or find a version of the library that's old enough to still support Python 2.

Comment: If you are only just learning the basics, you should probably ignore Python 2, and spend your time on the currently recommended and supported version of the language, which is Python 3.